# Test Django with Mysql 8.0 datetime incompatible

Tags: django, mysql-8.0

Test Django with Mysql 8.0 datetime incompatible.

I'm trying to run tests with mysql 8.0, however I'm encountering some inconsistencies. Could someone help with this?

Mysql 8.0.11
Django 2.0.4

```
> AttributeError at /admin/login/ 
>
>'datetime.datetime' object has no
> attribute 'split' 
>
>Request Method:    
>
>POST Request
> URL:  http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ 
>
Django
> Version:  2.0.4 
>
>Exception Type:    AttributeError Exception Value: 
> 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split' 
>
>Exception
> Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py
> in _DATETIME_to_python, line 506 Python
> 
>
>Executable:    /usr/local/bin/python Python Version:   3.6.5
```

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME' : 'dev',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'root',
        'HOST' : 'Maria1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8',
            'autocommit': True,
        }
    }
}

Comment: I'm trying to access the admin. I did not create any code yet.

Comment: try by changing 'ENGINE' to django.db.backends.mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Connector/Python 8.0.11 now returns SQL DATETIME column type as Python's [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). I think previously it was `str` type, therefore Django has problem with it, because treats datetime.datime as str(ing).

Comment: Got it. Is there any way to change that? Thank you

Comment: Which MySQL DB API Driver do you use? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers If native one, please try to use official one https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

> DATABASES = {
>       'default': {
>           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
>           'NAME' : 'dev',
>           'USER' : 'root',
>           'PASSWORD' : 'root',
>           'HOST' : 'Maria1',
>           'OPTIONS': {
>               'autocommit': True,
>           }
>       } }